# Spring Boot: Hibernate and Flyway boot order

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I have created Spring application. Pom xml is attached.

It has a config like this (below) and some db/migration/V1__init.sql for Flyway db migration tool.

It has hsqldb in-memory database and it is created after application is started. It is clean after creation.

I want Hibernate to create a schema based on entity classes and then Flyway fills the tables. Now Flyway starts V1__init.sql before tables is created and throw an exception. How can I change this order or what solution can I do?

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For using 'LEGACYHTML5' mode in Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should remove many of the versions from your pom and let Boot configure them for you. And you certainly shouldn't mix versions of Spring Boot itself (you have 1.3.2.RELEASE and 1.3.3.RELEASE).

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue.

I wanted my schema to be created by hibernate because of it's database independence.  I already went through the trouble of figuring out a nice schema for my application in my jpa classes,  I don't like repeating myself.

But I want some data initialization to be done in a versioned manner which flyway is good at.

Spring boot runs flyway migrations before hibernate. To change it I overrode the spring boot initializer to do nothing.  Then I created a second initializer that runs after hibernate is done.  All you need to do is add this configuration class:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

@Configuration
public class MigrationConfiguration {


    /**
     * Override default flyway initializer to do nothing
     */
    @Bean
    FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, (f) ->{} );
    }


    /**
     * Create a second flyway initializer to run after jpa has created the schema
     */
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
    FlywayMigrationInitializer delayedFlywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, null);
    }


}
```

That code needs java 8,  If you have java 7 or earlier,  replace `(f)->{}` with an inner class that implements [FlywayMigrationStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayMigrationStrategy.html)

Of course you can do this in xml just as easily.

Make sure to add this to your application.properties:

```
flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
```

Comment: This works great.  Instead of @DependsOn I prefer to just declare a parameter (then it's strongly typed) but this overriding of the flyway initialisation is extremely useful.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice but i tried it and it cant locate my entitymanagerfactory by its name.

Comment: Have you added spring data jpa to your pom.xml?  check what auto-configuration is doing.  Or like Paul Hilliar said inject it by type

Comment: this seems deprecated on the latest version of flyway,flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true

Comment: this no longer works for Spring Boot 2.1.8. After upgrading from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8, the app cannot start with an error claiming:
Circular depends-on relationship between 'delayedFlywayInitializer' and 'entityManagerFactory'

Comment: Yep, it does not work anymore. What is the alternative?

Comment: @Kikin-Sama I had to turn off autoconfiguration `spring.flyway.enabled=false` and create new instance manually `Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource).load();`

Comment: tried this but getting, Parameter 0 of method flywayInitializer in com.ninja.app.MigrationConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' that could not be found

Answer (score 23):

All SQL migrations will start after Hibernate creates all the tables.

Spring Boot 2.2.2, Flyway 6.0.8

To disable boot for Flyway, insert into resources/application.properties:

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

Create separate configuration for Flyway to make it load when Hibernate is ready:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public FlywayConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
        Flyway.configure().baselineOnMigrate(true).dataSource(dataSource).load().migrate();
    }
}
```

Start your migration scripts from version 2:

```
resources/db.migration/V2__fill-tables.sql
```

V1 is used as a baseline, V1 file will be ignored.

Comment: Works with Spring Boot 2.6.3 and 8.4.4

Comment: Works for me with Spring Boot 2.7.6 and flyway 8.5.13

Comment: Great! Works with spring-boot version 3.0.5. Just add ```.baselineVersion("0.0")``` to the configuration, and even run migration V1.

Answer (score 18):

Spring Boot auto-configuration of Flyway ensures that database migrations have run before Hibernate is initialised. In other words, you can't rely on Flyway auto-configuration and use Flyway to populate tables created by Hinernate.

One solution is to fully embrace Flyway and use it to both create the tables and populate them. You can then switch off Hibernate's table creation (`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`). This approach is more robust as it will allow your database to evolve more easily. This is what I would recommend that you do.

Another solution is to disable auto-configuration of Flyway (`flyway.enabled=false`) and to configure it your self. You can then configure Flyway to depend on Hibernate so that Hibernate has created the tables before Flyway tries to populate them.

Comment: Do you have any sample code of your second suggestion?

Comment: We wish that were true.  Actually Hibernate currently runs first and this is an open issue.

Comment: @sofend I believe you are mistaken and the question suggests so too. We also have tests in Boot that verify that Flyway migrations run before Hibernate. What makes you think that Hibernate runs first?

Comment: Hey, if so, that's welcome news.  I've got what I assume to be a pretty vanilla configuration running on the latest Spring Boot release (1.4.3.RELEASE).  I'm using the latest test framework annotations.  I'm happy to share some of my config.  Or, if you've got it working, probably makes sense to see what you have and learn that way.  (Are you using Spring Boot, or just straight Spring?)

The issue I'm running into is not running Flyway to do data population (which is what the person who started this thread was doing).  I'm using Flyway to migrate the schema and want Hibernate to validate it.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson `Flyway ensures that database migrations have run before Hibernate is initialised`, have you managed to find particular piece of code validating that statement? This is not mentioned within their documentation

Answer (score 3):

For more recent users that use Spring Boot +2.1 and as @mota commented into @user3707816's answer, you can use **spring.flyway.enabled=false** in application.properties and then create a new instance manually:

```
Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource)
                .baselineOnMigrate(true)
                .schemas(PG_DATABASE_SCHEMA)//optional, by default is public
                .load().migrate();
```

Comment: Did this but after that getting, Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with Spring Boot 2.3.1

1- you need to disable boot for Flyway, by insert into resources/application.properties:

```
spring.flyway.enabled = false
```

2- Start your migration scripts from version 2 as V1 is used as a baseline, V1 file will be ignored.

3- Make the **@SpringBootApplication** class implements **CommandLineRunner** interface (It is used to execute the code after the Spring Boot application started
). and it will be like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Flyway.configure().baselineOnMigrate(true).dataSource(dataSource).load().migrate();
    }

}
```

[This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756544/4444367)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still wants to configure Flyway **as a bean** as of Spring Boot 2.1.8 and later, but is falling onto the circular dependency error, there is a way to exclude the `@DependsOn("flyway")` that the auto-configured `EntityManagerFactory` uses by default.

First, set `spring.flyway.enabled` to `false` and then create a class extending `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` so we can exclude the Flyway dependency before the beans are created. Example:

```
@Component
public class FlywayDeferrerPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        excludeDependsOnFlywayFromBean(beanFactory, DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.class);
        excludeDependsOnFlywayFromBean(beanFactory, EntityManagerFactory.class);
    }

    private void excludeDependsOnFlywayFromBean(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Class<?> beanClass) {
        Stream.of(beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(beanClass))
            .map(beanFactory::getBeanDefinition)
            .filter(it -> it.getDependsOn() != null && it.getDependsOn().length > 0)
            .forEach(it -> it.setDependsOn(Stream.of(it.getDependsOn()).filter(name -> !name.equals("flyway")).toArray(String[]::new)));
    }
}
```

This example is very minimal and could probably break on new versions. For instance, in my project, I did the same thing somewhat differently using a custom method `recursivelyExcludeDependencyOnFromBeanDefinition(EntityManagerFactory.class, Flyway.class)`, that finds all dependencies form `EntityManagerFactory` which also depends on Flyway, so we don't have to know, for example, that `DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` also depends on Flyway.

To make it all work, just add the bean definition normally:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
@DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
public Flyway flyway() { /* ... */ }
```

Of course, if you don't care about `Flyway` being available as a bean, then I would recommend using a custom `@Configuration` file like the one from [@pavelety's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58989276/260411).

Answer (score -1):

may be because of the order

add
on application.properties

```
flyway.out-of-order = true
```

or
application.yml on spring

```
flyway:
  out-of-order: true
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with execution order of Flyway/Hibernate.. so just for clarification: this setting will allow migrations to run out of order. I.e. `V2__migration.sql` might run after `V3__update.sql` has already been applied to the database (if flyway detects that it has not been run yet).

Comment: it will be risky! V11 will run before V9 and breaks your db.