# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I have a Spring Boot project in which Flyway is used along with JPA.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The project is running absolutely fine. Due to some requirements I had to change the order of Flyway loading so it is loaded after the Hibernate. I searched and found the following solution `https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806540/1361888`. I created the `MigrationConfiguration` as suggested as answer in the above link. Now when I run the application then it gives me following error,

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method flywayInitializer in 
com.x2iq.microservice.config.MigrationConfiguration required a bean of type 
'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' in your 
configuration.
```

Now I fairly new to Spring Boot so unable to understand this error and I could not find anything related to this error online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `@Configuration` class you would want to expose a Flyway Bean to the container. Something like this should do the trick:

```
@Configuration 
public class MigrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(){
        return new Flyway();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link :

Spring Configuration is given for flyway bean.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/

Example from my project:

```
<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="true" />
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:db/migration" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
```