# Execute JPA table creation before flyway migration script

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, flyway

I want to use this Spring properties file for database configuration.

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
request.limit=300000
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration
```

The code works well but unfortunately when database is empty after all tables are deleted I get SQL errors because migration script is executed first.

How I can configure JPA first to create tables and then flyway to execute migration script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flyway migration run before hibernate execution. You can do that by seeting boot order. For this you need to add this configuration class:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

@Configuration
public class MigrationConfiguration {


/**
 * Override default flyway initializer to do nothing
 */
@Bean
FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
    return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, (f) ->{} );
}


/**
 * Create a second flyway initializer to run after jpa has created the schema
 */
@Bean
@DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
FlywayMigrationInitializer delayedFlywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
    return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, null);
}


}
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097876/spring-boot-hibernate-and-flyway-boot-order) answer you will get details.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid circular dependencies write like this:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {

    @Bean
    FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, (f) -> {
        });
    }

    static class Dummy {
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("entityManagerFactory")
    Dummy delayedFlywayInitializer(Flyway flyway, FlywayProperties flywayProperties) {
        if (flywayProperties.isEnabled())
            flyway.migrate();
        return new Dummy();
    }
}
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806540/4773603) answer