# Spring Boot 2.3 fails to start when spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto equals to validate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring boot: 2.3.0.RELEASE application with Flyway: 6.4.1 and Hibernate: hibernate-core: 5.4.22.Final, hibernate-validator: 6.1.5.Final, hibernate-commons-annotations: 5.1.0.Final.

I tried searching for errors but cannot find a solution. I tried applying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097876/spring-boot-hibernate-and-flyway-boot-order), but whenever spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate is set, it doesn't work if I use `none`, `drop-create` value everything back to the norm.

I run MySQL 5.7 in Docker, and the database with tables is there.

The error is below:

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
> in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
> Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in
> org.cloudwheel.files.configuration.customer.persistence.CustomerRepository
> defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean
> property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Schema-validation: missing table [my_files]

How can I debug this? I see many such issues, but none of the solutions worked for me.

NOTE: The table `my_files` is present. I can verify this both via IntelliJ and MySQL Workbench. Also, I don't want to downgrade if possible.

**UPDATE:**

I am sure that a database isn't a problem:

> 2020-12-01 14:24:04.795  INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with
> port(s): 8080 (http) 2020-12-01 14:24:04.800  INFO 23295 --- [
> restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting
> service [Tomcat] 2020-12-01 14:24:04.800  INFO 23295 --- [
> restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting
> Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35] 2020-12-01 14:24:04.895  INFO
> 23295 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
> Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2020-12-01
> 14:24:04.895  INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
> initialization completed in 1762 ms 2020-12-01 14:24:07.982  INFO
> 23295 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    :
> Flyway Community Edition 6.4.1 by Redgate 2020-12-01 14:24:07.986
> INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
> : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 2020-12-01 14:24:08.090  INFO 23295 --- [
> restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1
>
> - Start completed. 2020-12-01 14:24:08.113  INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database:
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/files (MySQL 5.7) 2020-12-01 14:24:08.186
>   INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate
>   : Successfully validated 13 migrations (execution time 00:00.029s)
>   2020-12-01 14:24:08.199  INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema
>   `files`: 1.13 2020-12-01 14:24:08.200  INFO 23295 --- [
>   restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema
>   `files` is up to date. No migration necessary. 2020-12-01
>   14:24:08.268  INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing
>   ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2020-12-01 14:24:08.281
>   INFO 23295 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler
>   : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler' 2020-12-01 14:24:08.330
>   INFO 23295 --- [         task-1]
>   o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2020-12-01 14:24:08.374  INFO
>   23295 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    :
>   HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.22.Final

Comment: It is complaining about a missing table **not** about a missing database.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I fixed the typo. I meant table, not database.

Comment: Well the table isn't present, regardless what you think is. You are probably looking at a different database then your application is.

Comment: @M.Deinum Why all other options, except for `validate` will work then?

Comment: Because doesn't validate. It ignores everything (**none**) or changes the schema (**create**).

Comment: @M.Deinum I added logs before the error, and they clearly show that connection could have been established, migrations were applied. I connect to the same Docker. I don't have any other database/docker running. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225366/discussion-between-dmytro-chasovskyi-and-m-deinum).

Comment: The fact that 1 part can connect doesn't mean the other uses the same connection. I pretty sure that the connection used by hibernate is pointing somewhere different then flyway is using and what you are using to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M.Deinum mentioned in his comments Flyway and Hibernate might not have been connected to the same datasource. In my case, it was because of `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=true`. As soon as I removed this property, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my_files]`.

You say that the database `my_files` is present, but hibernate needs a table `my_files` to be present - for example you used annotation @Table(name = "my_files") or you have entity with name MyFiles.

Check whether the database contains the table `my_files`.

Comment: I use Kotlin, not Java but I have this entity in my code:

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_files")
data class MyFile