# Do I need to escape special characters in application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I've special characters such as " (doublequotes), @, ~, !, %, &, }, ] in the datasource password field. When I run my springboot app and when it attempts to connect to the database I run into -

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "problem accessing trust store"
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
```

My questions are :
(1) Is there a way to view what password is Spring using to attempt the connection?
(2) Do I need to escape any of the special characters in the password in the `application.properties`?

I was able to connect to the database using a standalone java program but I had to escape the double quotes in the password. I'm using Springboot-2.0.4, Flyway-5.2.4, jdk 1.8 and MS-SQL server on the backend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**application.properties**: No escaping is required for your specified characters.

If you use e.g. a backslash, you'd need to escape it with another backslash, like so: `C:\\Development\\mydir`

**application.yml**: Surround value with `"` and escape embedded `"` like this `\"`

Note: application.yml is outside question from OP. Use either *application.properties* **or** *application.yml*, not both.

Tested and verified with this entry in *application.properties*

```
myapp.entry-with-special-characters=@~!%&=""
```

And tested again with this entry in *application.yml*

```
myapp:
  entry-with-special-characters: "@~!%&=\"\""
```

Output value to console like this (put code inside e.g. class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, will run when application starts)

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner propertiesTest(@Value("${myapp.entry-with-special-characters}") String myVal) {
    return args -> System.out.printf("Test-output for StackOverflow: %s\n", myVal);
}
```

With Flyway, try this instead

```
/**
 * Override default flyway initializer to do nothing
 */
@Bean
FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway, @Value("${myapp.entry-with-special-characters}") String myVal) {
    System.out.printf("Test-output for StackOverflow: %s\n", myVal);
    return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, (f) ->{} );
}
```

[Spring Boot: Hibernate and Flyway boot order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097876/spring-boot-hibernate-and-flyway-boot-order)

[image]

Answer to the question

> Is there a way to view what password is Spring using to attempt the
> connection?

can be to replace the key `myapp.entry-with-special-characters` in the above bean with relevant key from *application.properties*. Please keep in mind that passwords are secrets.

Environment used during testing:

- Spring Boot 2.4.1
- JDK 14.0.2
- Windows 10 Home